# Parallelize for loops in java

Tags: java, multithreading, openmp

I had come across openMP, which could be used to parallelize the for loops in c, C++. Of course, OpenMP could do much more than just that. But i'm curious if we can parallelize the for loops in java to optimize the performance of the programs. Suppose i have n iterations in a for loop, is there a way to parallelly run these iterations?

Comment: Using Threads should help?

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Ideally, there is a more high-level solution, though.

Comment: If each iteration takes a lot of time and independent from previous computations in loop, then use ThreadPoolExecutor and submit calculations as tasks.

Comment: I would suggest trying a basic [google search](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=parallelize+for+loop+in+java) before submitting a question with lots of duplicates already on SO. See for instance [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686200/parallelizing-a-for-loop).

Comment: You can make collection iteration parallel using Java 8 streams.

Comment: check [omp4j](http://www.omp4j.org/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If each iteration takes a lot of time and independent from previous computations in loop, then use ExecutorServiceand submit calculations as tasks.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); // number of threads
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   // declare variables as final which will be used in method run below
   final int count = i;
   executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           //do your long stuff and can use count variable
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: When i try to do as u suggested, im getting the following error: Cannot refer to a non-final variables inside an inner class defined in a different method. My for loop deals with a few non-final variables.

Comment: Thanks, succinct and effective answer. Maybe add `executorService.shutdown()` to help sync things a bit.