# Is 'parallelizing' my for loop the right choice? (Without JNI/OPENMP)

Tags: java, for-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Edit: The answers given by 'Z Boson', 'Chiron' and 'Mattias F' are probably exactly what I need. However, I don't know any C or C++ which is a requirement for OPENMP and JNI. OpenCL does have existing third party Java API available, but I don't know how efficient the GPU will be for my needs. I found an interesting solution here: [Parallelizing a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686200/parallelizing-a-for-loop), but will this reduce my computation time by multiple hours?

I will eventually implement the C++ methodology, but for now I need a quick fix. Any additional advice?

---

I have a problem where I need to iterate a series of operations across all 2^n combinations of n elements, the code for which may be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577172/brute-force-optimally-deleting-2s-from-a-random-matrix-how-can-i-make-it-fas.

Until I figure out the maths behind my random matrices, I want to optimize the current process as much as possible because iterating across n = 24 takes hours even after configuring my Java JVM (hotspot) for high throughput via the command line. Hence, if I were to implement multiprocessing/parallel computing across all four of my CPU cores, would this substantially decrease the time to completion?

I ask because I know nothing about multiprocessing/threading nor its implementation and am only in a first semester introductory course to java. I don't want to waste time learning this if it's ill advised. Specifically, in this situation (from what I've read on S.O. thus far), I would submit at least 'n' batches of jobs where each batch contains at most all the combinations of 'x < n' elements from n for some x. Advice?

Comment: I should note that I've also looked at garbage collection, and while there are say, 6400 entries for n = 16, these 6400 entries only amount to ~13 seconds as an over-estimate. Thus, while this is something I'm interested in later on, I don't think it is important given the current run time.

Comment: If you want to create highly parralell code, you should look into OpenCL. It uses the graphics card to do your computations, and you can write a kernel that runs your "series of operations" on one cell in your matrix, and then run it across all cells.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; this is interesting. However, I don't have the time to contribute to another language at the moment. (looking into the java API right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using JNI and OPENMP to build a simple parallel environment, Since VM mechanism 
is anyway no match for native code speed ( like C/C++ ).

JNI is a java feature which enables you to call c procedure in java.

openmp(omp) is a c/c++ library which makes parallel computing very simple.

And,JNI is a very important Java feature, not ill adviced.

For jni, visit

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html

For omp pdf-docs visit

http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf

Finally, your implementation perhaps looks like that:

```
calcu.java

calcu.h

calcu.c
```

calcu.java:

```
//If this is a function in your class
public native float calculate(some parameters...);  //without implementation in java
```

calcu.h:

```
//generated by "javah" command automatically
//some thing above ommitted
JNIEXPORT float JNICALL Java_test_calculate(JNIEnv *, jclass, jbyteArray, jbyteArray);
// has this function declared in c automatically
```

calcu.c:

```
#include "calcu.h"
#include "omp.h"
//implement the java native call here
JNIEXPORT float JNICALL Java_test_calculate(JNIEnv *, jclass, jbyteArray, jbyteArray)
{
    ...some code;    
    /*Here for example, we use a omp compile command for parallel loop*/    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(...)
    {}       //this for will be automatically executed using parallel computing
}
```

Besides, the task above can also be done in eclipse java project.
You can convert a java project to C/C++ Make-file project in eclipse and use gcc/g++ build chain for jni. That would relieve you of much work on typing into a terminal.

=================================CUTCUTCUTCUTCUT=====================================

For those who don't want their java code gets messed around with C/C++, the following suggestion may be useful:

There is a coding mode called "Threads flood",from what I know, introduced by IBM .Cor.
The key idea of the tactic is to create as many threads as possible during parallel-able procedure to reach the limit of VM's native task-dispatching performance.

A demonstration shall look like that:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test{

    public test()
    {
        super();
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
          ResultJoin rj=new ResultJoin();
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
          {
            Task t=new Task(1.0*i,2.0*i);
            new Emmitable(rj,t).start();
          }
          System.out.println(rj.getReuslt());
          return;
    }
}

interface TaskInterface
{
    public double calcu();
}

interface ResultInterface
{
    public void pushResult(double dat);
    public double getReuslt();
}


class Emmitable extends Thread
{
    private ResultInterface result=null;
    private TaskInterface task=null;

    public Emmitable(ResultInterface rj,TaskInterface tsk)
    {result=rj;task=tsk;}

    public void run()
    {
        result.pushResult(task.calcu());
    }

}
class ResultJoin implements ResultInterface
{
    private double sum=0;
    public ResultJoin()
    {}
    public synchronized void pushResult(double i)
    {
        sum+=i;
    }
    public synchronized double getReuslt()
    {
        double result=sum;
        return sum;
    }
}

class Task implements TaskInterface
{
    private double a;
    private double b;
    public Task(double na,double nb)
    {
        a=na;b=nb;
    }
    public double calcu()
    {
        return 1.0*a*b;
    }
}
```

The intuitive effect of the code is to set a bunch of thread "On Fly" and collect their result into one place.

When to use this mode is better?

when each of your parallel-structure is quite sophisticated(not sth like 'sum+=i'), this mode will provide considerable performance.

However if your parallel task is as simple as 'sum=sum+i*j', execute it directly without any paralleling is actually better. Because, under micro-scope, "new Object().start()" takes much longer than your simple task of several lines.

Comment: In case you're interested I wrote code in C with OpenMP and use JNA to integrate it into java. It was over 100 times faster than the single threaded java code the mathematicians in the group were using. Of course I only use java when I am order to so probably some Java hotshots could have done better than what we had https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479258/cholesky-decomposition-with-openmp

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll start looking into everything now.

Comment: However, is there any advice if I don't know any C or C++ at all? It might take a while to teach myself the language and I currently don't have that kind of time.

Comment: I've updated the answer for your confusions. Please check it above if you see this reply.

Comment: Chiron, Last night I also taught myself how to write constructors and use ExecutorService at a beginner's level. I'll be answering my own question too with this implementation once I fully understand everything (your's is MUCH better, however). My 'parallelization' reduced the run-time from 1-2+ days to 3.9 hours for 2^24 (16,777,216) combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after a few days of effort I rewrote my code from scratch after it works 3000 times faster. I can now do 2^24 combinations in 5 seconds and 2^34 combinations in 2.5 hours. The code for this solution may be found at :

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260970/improving-efficiency-of-code

To 'parallelize' my code, I used ExecutorService and InvokeAll. If anyone has any questions, I'll be happy to help! I taught all this to myself through online resources.

```
class StringTask implements Callable<Integer> {
    private List<List<Integer>> matTan;
    private List<int[]> combination;
    private List<int[]> jobs;
    private boolean gumDrop;
    private int minimum;

    StringTask(List<int[]> a, List<int[]> b, List<List<Integer>> c, int d, boolean e) {
        this.combination = b;
        this.minimum = d;
        this.gumDrop = e;
        this.matTan = c;
        this.jobs = a;
    }

    public Integer call() {
        for (int[] e : jobs) {
            //Process my data
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And (where Search.finalize is called in my main method)

```
class Search {
    public static void finalize(List<List<Integer>> matTan, boolean gumDrop, int minimum) {
        //Process data
        int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

        List<List<int[]>> ranTime = new ArrayList<List<int[]>>(2 * threads);            
        for (int x = 0; x < 2 * threads; x++) {
            List<int[]> jobs = new ArrayList<int[]>(90);
            ranTime.add(jobs);
        }

        while (condition) {
           //Process more data (create the Collections in ranTime)
           if (condition) {
               processInputs(ranTime, combination, matTan, service);
           }
        }

       service.shutdown();
    }

    private static void processInputs(List<List<int[]>> ranTime, List<int[]> combination,                           List<List<Integer>> matTan, ExecutorService service) {
        Collection<StringTask> collection = new ArrayList<StringTask>(ranTime.size());      
        for (List<int[]> jobs : ranTime) {
            StringTask analysis = new StringTask(jobs, combination, matTan);
            collection.add(analysis);
        }

        try {
            List<Future<Integer>> futures = service.invokeAll(collection);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```