# Parallelizing double nested for loop

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, concurrenthashmap

I have a very large lists, so I need to speed up the whole, I'm trying to  parallelize this for loop:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getData()
{
    //Both list are ArrayList<String>
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int w = 0; w < firstList.size(); w++) {
        boolean once = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < secondList.size(); j++) {
            if (!once && secondList.get(j).var.startsWith(firstList.get(w).var.toLowerCase())) {
                hashMap.put(firstList.get(w).var, secondList.get(j).var);
                once = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return hashMap;
}
```

I've found this good answer [Parallelizing a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686200/parallelizing-a-for-loop), but not really understand how to apply it to my case, I should create two `Callable <output>` for `<K, V>` of my `HashMap` ?

Or am I doing wrong to use this method ?

Comment: I doubt parallelizing would have any impact. Start by finding the unique element of the second list that you use as value for all the elements of the map only once, instead of doing it for every element of the first list. Initialize the map with an appropriate size, too. You should also define "very large". And of course, unless you're absolutely sure that the lists are random access, you should use a foreach loop.

Comment: If `otherCondition` is `false`, you can just reduce that to `return new HashMap<>();`... And if it is `true`, you're only ever adding the first element of `secondList`, so why a second for loop?

Comment: I very simplified example , in reality the otherCondition varies depending on the lists of variables @JBNizet

Comment: Don't oversimplify the example, otherwise it makes no sense anymore.

Comment: I've added the otherCondition check @JBNizet

Comment: What is very large? What is the concrete type of both lists? Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: I need to iterate over all the elements of the first list in order (size of firstList 281, secondList 65000), the String type is correct for hashMap and list, I use java 8 @JBNizet

Comment: My question is: what is the type of the lists? ArrayList? LinkedList? Something else?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood, ArrayList @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not how to parallelize the loop. You are using the wrong approach.
If I understand correctly you want for each element of list 1 to add in a hashmap 1 entry from list 2 that starts with the same string.
First of all I don't understand why you don't break out of the loop when you find a match and you use the `once` variable.
Also why do you need `once` variable since you can check if the word of list1 already exists in the hashmap?
Anyway you should be using a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (check NavigableMap interface) instead of a hashmap which checks for close matches.
Also why can't you do this logic when creating the lists in the first place?
Perhaps you are trying to optimise the wrong thing?

Comment: Even stopping the cycle (tried) does not decrease the time,
for each element of the list 1 is added to that found in the list 2 with the same " name " of the list 1

Comment: @MicheleLacorte stopping the inner loop as soon as you found your match should decrease the time, unless all the matches don't exist or are at the end of the first list. Not calling toLowerCase() every time is also a quick and easy win, and makes the code more readable.

Comment: @MicheleLacorte:The only case that breaking the loop early doesn't improve time since as you said the lists are very very big, means that the data are "problematic"  i.e. no matches or very rare matches which would cause the double loop to go over all elements. If that is the case then you are trying to optimize the wrong thing. Show us what you are trying to do/solve in the first place. Most probably you should never have been ended up with 2 lists of strings to process.

Comment: @Jim The code is Java on Android , I'm doing the parse a list of EPG in `XML` format , the class that does the parse returns `ArrayList` 2 (first : `EPGChannel` , second: `EPGProgram` ) and I have a list of channels (personal) to which I need to match the EPG which is now running, with name `EPGChannel.startWith(myChannelName)` and check on `currentTimeInMillis` from EPGProgram and `System.currentTimeInMillis`. So i need to iterate on full personal channel list to associate EPG on every channels

Comment: @MicheleLacorte:I am sorry I am don't understand what you are talking about. I would recommend at this point to put everything of `list1` in a `TreeMap` and then loop over `list2` checking if the string exists using the methods of `Navigable` interface. You would reduce `O(N^2)` to `O(N)`.

Comment: Thanks!! and @JBNizet

Answer (score 1):

I would start by rewriting it with streams. Not only will that make the code parallelizable, but it will also make it more readable. It will also avoid all the repetitions present in the original code, and make sure to iterate on the lists in an optimal way:

```
private static final class Entry {
    private final String first;
    private final String second;

    // constructor, getters left as an exercise
}

public Map<String, String> getData() {
    return firstList.stream()
        .flatMap(firstListElement -> {
            String lowercase = firstListElement.toLowerCase();
            return secondList.stream()
                             .filter(secondListElement -> secondListElement.startsWith(lowercase))
                             .limit(1)
                             .map(secondListElement -> new Entry(firstListElement, secondListElement));
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getFirst, Entry::getSecond));   
}
```

Then I would measure the time it takes to execute that, and compare the time it takes to execute the same code but with `firstList.parallelStream()` instead.

Comment: I can't call Entry::getFirst with getter method...
@JBNizet

Comment: That's unclear. What happens precisely. This code compiles and runs fine if you add the getters as indicated by the comment. If it doesn't, then either you're doing something wrong, or you're not actually using Java 8.

Comment: I use it on Android @JBNizet

Comment: AFAIK, Android is still stuck at Java 6.

Comment: It support Java 8 on new SDK

Comment: So, if you use Java 8, what happens **precisely**?

Comment: **Cannot resolve method 'getFirst'** it's clear! The method is `public static String getFirst()` a simple getter

Comment: A simple getter is not static. How could your static getter return the value of a non-static field? Post your code in the question.

Comment: This make no difference @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the work in parallel (on the outer list). But with a list which is only 281, this likely does not add much value.

On the inner list, if it only mattered that you find a match, not the first match, then that work could be parallelized as well, which would be more likely to have significant impact.

```
final ConcurrentMap<String, String> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
firstList.stream()
         .unordered()
         .parallel()
         .map(v1 -> v1.var)
         .forEach(var -> {
             final String lowerVar1 = var.toLowerCase();
             secondList.stream()
                       .filter(v2 -> v2.var.startsWith(lowerVar1))
                       .findFirst()
                       .ifPresent(v2 -> results.put(var, v2.var);
         });
```